# Различие адреса и указателя в аргументе функции

Tags: c, функции, указатели, адрес

Есть ли существенная разница в записывании аргумента функции, которая должна получить указатель на элемент i-го элемента массива a данных двух способов?

```
... имя функции(тип* х) {...}
```

1. Способ имя_функции(&a[i]);
2. Способ имя_функции(a + i);

В обоих случаях можно использовать разные арифметические операции с указателем (типа сложения, вычитания и др).

Comment: И несущественной тоже не видно...

Answer (score 6):

Нет, никакой разницы нет. В языке С выражение `&a[i]` по определению эквивалентно `&*(a + i)`, где пара операторов `&*` по определению "взаимоуничтожается" (является невычисляемой), оставляя просто `a + i`.

Утверждение о невычислении соседней пары `&*` (явной или неявной) было добавлено в стандарт C99 специально для того, чтобы сделать определенным поведение выражения `&a[n]`, где `n` - размер массива `a`.

К аргументам функций эта эквивалентность никак не привязана - она имеет место во всех контекстах.

Answer (score 1):

Результат этих вызовов функции

```
Способ имя_функции(&a[i]);
Способ имя_функции(a + i);
```

эквивалентен.

Однако в первом случае компилятор сгенерирует больше машинных команд, так как сначала он должен получить выражение `a[i]`, которое вычисляется как `*( a + i )`, а затем к этому выражению применить оператор взятия адреса `&`. То есть в итоге получается выражение вида `&*( a + i )`, которое эквивалентно выражению `( a + i )`.

Из стандарта C (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting):

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is **that E1[E2] is identical
>   to (*((E1)+(E2)))**. Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero)

Даже если компилятор оптимизирует объектный код, тем не менее нет никакой необходимости писать такое сложное выражение.

В сущности какой вариант выбрать зависит от вашего вкуса, и какой вариант по вашему мнению более выразителен в текущем контексте.

Comment: Действительно, оптимизирует https://godbolt.org/z/4pkjR0

Comment: Я думаю, что формально в одном случае этот код не эквивалентен. Когда мы прибавляем к a длину массива. Сложить мы эти указатели можем, а разыменовывать результат нельзя. Во всех остальных случаях либо всё нормально, либо и там, и там UB.

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев: Нет. Спецификация языка С специально постулирует тот факт, что соседние `&*` (как явные, так и неявные) являются *невычисляемыми*, чтобы легализовать выражение `&a[i]` в ситуациях, когда `i` равно длине массива. Никакого UB тут нет. Никакой "оптимизиции" тут нет тоже и говорить об "оптимизациях" тут бессмысленно: если две конструкции семантически эквивалентны, то они порождают одинаковый код. Никакого отношения к "оптимизациям" эта эквивалентность не имеет.